# CS50 pset 3 Plurality - Works until…Segmentation fault, and not enough vote prompts?

Tags: c, struct, command-line, command-prompt, cs50

Task is to have people type in their votes for the candidates given in the command line, then the most voted candidate wins. I only need to and am allowed to write code for the last two function prototypes.

So for now, the plurality code works fine...until the voter types an invalid name, then the program stops with a "segmentation fault". I don't get what causes this exactly. What should I do to fix this?

I had a previous code version, where this doesn't happen. So when a false name is typed in, it will print out "Invalid vote" as it should be. However, even then there was the problem that there was no more prompts left, so if there are 3 voters, then after 3 prompts the program ends. That's fine if everyone types in correctly. But if there is one invalid vote, then the program would only have two valid vote inputs before it ends.

Then about the "print winner" function, is there any function in CS50 that allows me to pick the largest candidates[i].votes or does it have to be solved differently...?

Thanks!

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

// Max number of candidates
// "the MAX here is a constant (equal to 9) that you can use now"
#define MAX 9

// Candidates have name and vote count
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];

// Number of candidates
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(string name);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: plurality [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }

    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        string name = get_string("Vote: ");

        // Check for invalid vote
        if (!vote(name))
        {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        }
    }

    // Display winner of election
    print_winner();
}

// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(string name)
{
    // TODO
    for (int h = 0; h < MAX; h++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)
            {   
                printf("Match\n");
                candidates[i].votes++;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    return 0;
}

// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    // TODO
    printf("The winner is...");
    return;
}
```

Comment: The number of candidates is stored in `candidate_count`. But in the `vote()` function, you're checking every candidate up to `MAX`. As a result, you're passing non-existent string pointers to `strcmp()`, causing it to access memory not allocated to your program.

Answer (score 0):

How many candidates are there? It depends of course on what is entered at the command line and it cannot be greater than MAX. What happens here `for (int h = 0; h < MAX; h++)` if there are 3 candidates entered? It tries to look at candidate 4 (index 3)! That is likely where the seg fault lies. [Here's advice](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/37065/do-you-know-how-to-find-a-seg-fault-advice-to-new-programmers) on finding the seg fault yourself; an important skill for every programmer.

Why are there two loops in the `vote` function? The `h` loops looks extraneous because the `i` loop will return. (the `i` loop has the same MAX problem!)

"*... is there any function in CS50 that allows me to pick the largest candidates[i].votes...*". Simple answer, No.

Answer (score 0):

**Fix for segmentation fault** -- The problem lies with the `return 0;` statement in the implementation of the `bool` function. You gotta delete that. Well, why have you put it there? `return 0` or `return EXIT_SUCCESS` typifies the return code of the main function here (and not the bool function) as passed back to the operating system. Just to let you know, if you do not hard code that `return 0;` statement at the end of the main function, modern C/C++ compilers will automatically do it for you.

**The solution to the print_winner function**

```
// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    int highestVotes = 0;
    // find highest number of votes
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
        if (candidates[i].votes > highestVotes)
            highestVotes = candidates[i].votes;
        
    // print winner(s)
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
        if (candidates[i].votes == highestVotes)
            printf("Winner: %s\n", candidates[i].name);
        
    return;
}
```